# UIDatePicker with UIToolbar error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using UIDatePicker and implement UIToolBar when click on UITextField. But When I click on textfield its crash. I'm using following code.

```
datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; 
[datepicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate]; 
[datepicker addTarget:self action:@selector(changeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

UIToolbar *toolbar= [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,44)]; 
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault; 
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]; 
UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismiss)];

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceLeft, doneButton, nil]];

[datepicker addSubview:toolbar];

textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;

textField.inputView = datepicker;
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Please file a radar on
>   UIKit with this log if you see this assertion. selectorString =
>   setTitle:, exercisedImplementations = {
>       "setTitle:" =     (
>       ); }'

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting an *Objective-C Exception* breakpoint in Xcode to see what line causes the error exactly?

Comment: Also, this code is running on the main thread (Thread 0), right?

Comment: Yes its right. did you have any solution?

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Where is the above code called?

Comment: I have call above code in Viewdidload. But not working. Please suggest me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Setting a `UITextField`s `inputAccessoryView` to a view that already has a superview will cause a crash.

So, Don't add the toolbar as a subview of the `UIDatePicker`. Remove

```
[datepicker addSubview:toolbar];
```

and just set

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

and the toolbar will appear above the data picker.